# how to display post data by category with laravel livewire

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

Good afternoon, how to display post data by category in laravel livewire? here I want to try to display post by category data in the following way but it still doesn't work:

web.php

```
Route::get('category/{category:slug}',[FrontController::class, 'category'])->name('category');
```

FrontController.php

```
public $search;
    public function category(Category $category)
    {
        $categories = Category::all();
        $general = General::find(1);
        $locale = App::currentLocale();

        $category_id = $category->id;
        $search = request("search");

        $posts = Post::where([
            ['lang',$locale],
            ['category_id',$category_id],
            ['status','PUBLISH'],
        ])->latest()->paginate(12);

        if ($this->search !== null) {
            $posts = Post::where([
                ['title','like', '%' . $this->search . '%'],
                ['lang',$locale],
                ['category_id',$category_id],
                ['status','PUBLISH'],
            ])->latest()->paginate(12);
        }

        // dd($category_id);
        $tags = Tag::all();
        $top        = Post::where('status','PUBLISH')->orderBy('views','desc')->limit(5)->get();
        return view ('front.category',compact('categories','category_id','general','locale','posts','tags','top'));
    }
```

category.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.front')

@section('content')
<main id="main">
    <section class="post-category">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row mt-3">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12 d-none d-lg-block">
                    <div class="sticky-top" style="top: 90px;">
                        <div class="card mb-3 rounded-3">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
                                    <img src="{{ asset('front/img/ads.png') }}" alt="..." height="300" width="279" class="card-img-top" />
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="d-flex flex-column mb-3 bg-light shadow bg-body rounded">
                            <div class="card-header bg-primary bg-gradient text-white fw-bold fs-5">
                                {{ __('sentence.category') }}
                            </div>
                            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                                @foreach ($categories as $category)
                                    <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                        <a href="{{ route('category', $category->slug) }}">{{ $category->name }}</a>
                                    </li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="d-flex flex-column bg-light bg-body shadow-lg rounded-3">
                            <div class="card-header bg-primary bg-gradient text-white fw-bold fs-5">
                                Tags
                            </div>
                            <div class="p-3 overflow-auto" style="max-height: 42vh">
                                <div class="nav tag-cloud">
                                    @foreach ($tags as $tag)
                                        <a href="{{ route('tag', $tag->slug) }}">{{ $tag->name }}</a>
                                    @endforeach   
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="category_id" value="{{ $category_id }}">
                <livewire:category-index>
                    
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="sticky-top" style="top: 90px;">
                        <div class="card rounded-3 shadow-lg mb-3">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <img src="{{ asset('front/img/ads1.png') }}" height="117" width="279" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="bg-light shadow bg-body rounded-3 mb-3">
                            <div class="card-header bg-primary bg-gradient text-white fw-bold fs-5">
                                {{ __('sentence.top_article') }}
                            </div>
                            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush mb-2">
                                @foreach ($top as $top)
                                <li class="list-group-item">
                                    <a href="{{ route('blogShow', $top->slug) }}">{{ $top->title }}</a>
                                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between mt-3">
                                        <small class="text-muted">{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($top->created_at)->format("d F, Y") }}</small>
                                        <small class="text-muted">{{ $top->views }} views </small>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="d-flex flex-column mb-3 bg-light shadow bg-body rounded d-lg-none d-xl-none">
                            <div class="card-header bg-primary bg-gradient text-white fw-bold fs-5">
                                {{ __('sentence.category') }}
                            </div>          
                            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                                @foreach ($categories as $category)
                                    <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                        <a href="{{ route('category', $category->slug) }}">{{ $category->name }}</a>
                                    </li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="d-flex flex-column bg-light bg-body shadow-lg rounded-3 d-lg-none d-xl-none">
                            <div class="card-header bg-primary bg-gradient text-white fw-bold fs-5">
                                {{ __('sentence.tag') }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="p-3 overflow-auto" style="max-height: 42vh">
                                <div class="nav tag-cloud">
                                    @foreach ($tags as $tag)
                                        <a href="{{ route('tag', $tag->slug) }}">{{ $tag->name }}</a>
                                    @endforeach   
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</main>
@endsection

@push('scripts')
@livewireScripts
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onscroll = function (ev) {
        if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
            window.livewire.emit('category-index');
        }
    };

</script>

<script>
    document.getElementById('load-more').onclick = function() {
        window.livewire.emit('category-index');
    };
</script>
@endpush
```

livewire\CategoryIndex.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\{Category, Post};
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

class CategoryIndex extends Component
{
    public $limitPerPage = 10;

    public $search;

    protected $listeners = [
        'category-index' => 'CategoryIndex'
    ];

    protected $updatesQueryString = [
        ['search' => ['except' => '']],
    ];
   
    public function CategoryIndex()
    {
        $this->limitPerPage = $this->limitPerPage + 6;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $locale = App::currentLocale();

        $category_id = request('category_id');
        
        $posts = Post::where([
            ['lang',$locale],
            ['category_id',$category_id],
            ['status','PUBLISH'],
        ])->latest()->paginate($this->limitPerPage);

        if ($this->search !== null) {
            $posts = Post::where([
                ['title','like', '%' . $this->search . '%'],
                ['lang',$locale],
                ['category_id',$category_id],
                ['status','PUBLISH'],
            ])->latest()->paginate($this->limitPerPage);
        }
        
        $this->emit('postStore');

        dd($category_id);

        return view('livewire.category-index', ['posts' => $posts]);
    }
}
```

livewire\category-index.blade.php

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div id="section-title" class="section-title p-1 pt-3">
        <h2 class="text-center fw-bold">{{ trans('sentence.recent_posts')}}</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-search mb-3">
        <span class="bi bi-search form-control-feedback"></span>
        <input type="text" wire:model="search" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ __('sentence.search_form') }}">
    </div>
    @foreach ($posts as $data)
    <div class="card bg-light shadow bg-body rounded-3 mb-2">
        <div class="card-header bg-primary text-white d-flex justify-content-between">
            <small>by {{$data->admin->name}}</small>
            <small>{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($data->created_at)->format("d F, Y") }}</small>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h2 class="card-title">
                <a href="{{ route('blogShow', $data->slug) }}">{{ $data->title }}</a>
            </h2>
            <div class="card-footer bg-body d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center pb-0 px-0">
                <div class="d-flex my-1">
                    @foreach ($data->tags as $tag)
                    <a href="{{ route('tag', $tag->slug) }}" class="badge {{ $tag->bg }} me-1 shadow-sm text-white">{{ $tag->name }}</a>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
    @if ($posts->count() == 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        Data not found!
    </div>
    @endif
    @if($posts->count() >= 10)
    <div class="text-center d-md-none d-lg-none d-xl-none">
        <button id="load-more" class="btn btn-primary my-3">
        Load More
        </button>
    </div>
    @endif
</div>
```

If I add`($category_id);` in `FrontController.php` the id of that category appears, but if I try to dd in `livewire\CategoryIndex.php` it shows **null**. what is the correct way to display posts by category? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Livewire components work slightly differently to blade views, they do not automatically inherit variables from their parents.

What you need to do is pass your `category_id` to the Livewire component.

```php
class CategoryIndex extends Component
{
  public $categoryId;
}
```

```html
<livewire:category-index :categoryId="$category_id" />
```

Comment: thank's for your answer @Peppermintology. do you mean it should be made like this?
in CategoryIndex.php i changed it like this,

add public $category_id;

and change
`$posts = Post::where([['lang',$locale],['category_id',$this->category_id],['status','PUBLISH']])->latest()->paginate($this->limitPerPage);`

Comment: and then, in category.blade.php, i changed it like this, <livewire:category-index :category_id="$category_id" />. but still not work

Comment: @HilmiHidayat It is probably to do with the underscore in your variable and how Livewire automatically infers things. I have updated my answer for you.

Comment: hi @Peppermintology , thanks a lot for helping me solve this problem. Now I have another problem when I want to display post data based on tags. can you help me again in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67887866/12571724) .thx :)